# Highlighting cell values based on column text

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with 3000 rows and column F through BQ. I want to highlight specific cells that has value > 0 where the text in column F contains "X" . how do i write a VBA macro for it?

I tried the below code but i am not successful :

```
Sub ConCol()
Set iRow = Range("F2:BQ3000")

For Each cell In iRow
  If cell.Value <> "" And Columns("$F") = "X" Then
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 105, 108)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do this using conditional formatting - do you absolutely need to use VBA?

Comment: If you must use VBA, be aware that `cells that has value > 0` is not equivalent to `cell.Value <> ""`, you should use `cell.Value > 0` instead. But as BigBen mentions, conditional formating does exactly what you ask for.

Comment: Yes! so i can have the process repeatable and can implement for other text

Comment: @Goal7 Then instead of hardcoding the text in the formula for your conditional formating, refer to a cell instead. Change the value of the cell, different cells get highlighted

Comment: Did you mean for the cell to "Contain X" or to equal "X"?

Comment: @Davesexcel Contain text "X" . For example Goal X . i updated the columns to A through BQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be several variations:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, Sh As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set Sh = ActiveSheet
    With Sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range("G2:BQ" & LstRw)
        For Each c In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
            If c > 0 Then
                If InStr(UCase(.Cells(c.Row, "F")), "X") Then
                    c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 105, 108)
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it's work fine in my side.
If column F contain X, I highlight all cells in a row that contain X also.

```
Sub ConCol()

'loop on each row
For i = 1 To 3000 ' row

    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value, "X") > 0 Then ' first condition : if col F contain X
        'loop on each column BQ = 69
        For j = 1 To 69

        If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value, "x") > 0 Then 'second condition : in each cell a selected row, if contain X
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 105, 108)
        End If

        Next j

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Or this version, I highlight only column F :

```
Sub ConCol2()

'loop on each row
For i = 1 To 3000 ' row

    If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value, "X") > 0 Then

        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 105, 108)

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't optimized but looks for capitalized "X" within the column F of rows in the range. If present, it goes on to look at each cell in the other columns and if Isnumeric and > 0 it gets coloured.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ConCol()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim currentRow As Range, loopRange As Range, currentCell As Range

    With ActiveSheet

        Set loopRange = .Range("F2:BQ3000")

        For Each currentRow In loopRange.Rows
            If InStr(1, currentRow.Columns(1).Value, "X", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
                For Each currentCell In currentRow.Cells
                    If IsNumeric(currentCell.Value) And currentCell > 0 Then
                        currentCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 105, 108)
                    End If
                Next currentCell
            End If
        Next

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Be aware that my solution explicitly checks for an actual capital X in the cell not just any x. So be sure which you are after. Any x or X. Simply converting to upper case before testing is not the same. Depends what you are after.